# Version - Subversion database design for a c# application

Tags: c#, sql-server, versioning

I currently have an application that already runs on prod.

The problem I have is with versions. Currently, we only have version but no subversion, so in test environment, our version number already hit 100+. This is something that we don't want and this is why we'll be adding subversions.

My question is, would it be better to have 2 columns - version and subversion - in db or just a single column that holds the version as varchar and I parse the version in application level or in my stored procs?

If I chose to have only 1 column which holds version number like "3.5.6", what would be the best way to get the latest version in a stored procedure?

I'm using mssql2005

Thank you

Comment: You should consider using different names for the different parts of the version number. A typical scheme is major.minor.release.build or similar. I mention this because "Subversion" is the name of a popular version control system, so I would think quite a few would be confused about your title. Perhaps they won't even see what it is because they don't know Subversion.

Comment: Yes, that was the main problem while googling since nearly all results were related to SVN...

Answer (score 0):

Version numbers are arbitrary, they hold no meaning other than for your selves. If you have a special meaning that requires it to be in a separate field do it. Otherwise just stick in one. It should be easy enough to parse and extract in a later version.

Without seeing how you db is set up.. i wouldn't know how to get your version number out but say if you stored it in an Environment table. You would simple call a select on there.

e.g.

```
SELECT versionNumber FROM Environment
```

Comment: I currently have a stored procedure that gets the latest version details and I'm using select top... but since the versionnumber will no longer be an int - 3.1.5 instead of 3 - top won't work. I know how to write simple selects anyway..